# How to know if AJAX request is performed?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am learning AJAX,
so I have this HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>
    My first chat page
  </title>
  <meta charset = "utf-8">
  <style>
  #message-area {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #send-button {
    float: right;
    margin: 20px;
    color: white;
    background-color: green;
  }
  textarea {
    float: left;
    width: 90%;
    height: 4em;
    font-family: cursive;
    fon-size: 20px;
    resize: none;
  }

  </style>
</head>
<body>


  <div id="message-area">
      <textarea id="myTextarea" >
      </textarea>
      <button type="button" id="send-button">
        Send
      </button>

  </div>
</body>
<script>
var sendButton = document.getElementById("send-button");

function trial(){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            sendButton.innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
        xhttp.open("GET", "insertmessage.php", true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
}

sendButton.addEventListener("click", trial);

</script>
</html>
```

And I have this simple PHP code:

```
<?php
echo "hello";
?>
```

What I want is that when I click the send button, it sets up an AJAX connection, connects to the server, the server sends "Hello", and change the inner HTML of the send button. I tried them in the same folder in WAMP www directory, but it didn't work.

Comment: Where your `xmlhttp` comes from?

Comment: you can open the browser inspector, and check the network tab to see the request result

Comment: For starters, you need to say sendButton.addEventListener("click", trial) without the () after trial.

Comment: You're also missing a closing brace for the onreadystatechange function

Comment: Also, you should put quotes around insertmessage.php.  You will definitely have an error in to browser console from that.

Comment: Fixed the closing brace.

Comment: Fixed xml. Fixed quotes around insertmessage.php

Comment: Look at the network panel and developer console. Are there any errors in the console? Look for the network request, do you see it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just place

```
xhttp.open("GET", "insertmessage.php", true);
xhttp.send();
```

outside

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
}
```

your ajax is not send because this code is never executed since you put it inside your onreadystatechange event (this event only occur when your ajax request is send)

```
xhttp.open("GET", "insertmessage.php", true);
xhttp.send();
```

so your code would look like this

```
var sendButton = document.getElementById("send-button");

function trial(){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            sendButton.innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", "insertmessage.php", true);
    xhttp.send();

}

sendButton.addEventListener("click", trial);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do trial() in your eventListener assignment, trial is already run and makes an ajax call. It should already update html without clicking. You can verify your code here: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_get

Your button text should be updated otherwise there is a problem with your PHP server. Just put the fully constructed php url in a browser check the response.

For such debugging, browser debugging tools are very handy, e.g. chrome has a network tab which can tell you everything about your request.

Comment: When I request the php page, it says hello!

Comment: Network doesn't show anything when I click the button.

Comment: Can you explain the first part please. Do you mean that it would be called without clicking because I didn't store it in a variable? Like var x= function()?

Comment: sendButton.addEventListener("click", trial()); - trial gets executed.